# Monodevelop MVC Development Adding a View

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am building an MVC project on monodevelop, but I am having difficulties adding a view. When I click on the add view button, I encounter an error.

I think this error is already known by the monodevelop team as I found a ticket associated to this error here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6036

My questions are:

1. **Is this error fixed?** I am using MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2, which I installed on Ubuntu 12.10 using `apt-get install monodevelop`I attempted to update the version, but I'm not sure if its either up to date or if there is something about installing it in this manner.
2. **Is there a work-around for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it is fixed, but not in Ubuntu packages. It seems 13.04 has the same version of MonoDevelop as 12.10, so it should be still broken. You can try to submit a bug report and see if they update the package to a newer version.
2. The only workaround I know is to install a newer version of MonoDevelop. To do this, you can either use a PPA or build it yourself.

#### Using a PPA

A quick search returned [this](https://launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest) PPA. It provides the latest build of MonoDevelop, so if someone commits some change in the source code, those packages should be rebuilt and updated.

I have not used it, so I can't tell you how stable it is. Also as it offers MonoDevelop 4, during installation your mono runtime should be upgraded as well.

So, if using a PPA is an option and you want to have the latest and greatest MonoDevelop:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:keks9n/monodevelop-latest 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install monodevelop-latest
```

#### Building MonoDevelop by yourself

To build MonoDevelop, you need first to clone their git repo and required modules:

```
git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
cd monodevelop
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

After that you need to checkout the version you want. I only tried 3.1, but you can select a newer version:

```
git checkout monodevelop-3.1-series
```

Next, you need to install the build dependencies. You may want to take note of what will be installed, in case you want to remove them after compilation.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep monodevelop
```

Finally, you need to compile it as usual:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --profile=stable
make -j 4
sudo make install
```

**Note:** if you want you can replace `make install` with `checkinstall`: instead of copying the files to your root filesystem it will create a debian package (which is a lot easier to (un)install) and install it.

```
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=monodevelop-mygitbuild
```

Using this if you later need to remove it you just do a `sudo apt-get remove monodevelop-mygitbuild`.

At the end, you can run your build of MonoDevelop in a terminal with `/usr/local/bin/monodevelop`. If everything works fine you can create a launcher (you can use `/usr/share/applications/monodevelop.desktop` as base).

Comment: I used the ppa and it appeared to work. Except now when I add a controller or a view, I get the following error `Invalid SDK Version Name` Thanks

Comment: As of 6/14/2013: The ppa seems to be using monodevelop 3.1, which seems pretty stable.